# Concatenate columns from joined table with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have **3** EF entities: `Appeal`, `AppealPerson`, `Person`.

`Appeal` and `Person` entities joined by `AppealPerson` entity (many-to-many relation).
I want to select appeals with concatenated person full names.

```
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| AppealId | Appeal.* | Person.Surname + Person.Name + Person.MiddleName |
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1        | ..info.. | Aaa Aaa Aaa, Bbb Bbb Bbb, Ccc Ccc Ccc            |
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2        | ..info.. | Aaa Aaa Aaa, Bbb Bbb Bbb                         |
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I'm using this query:

```
context.Appeals
.Select(a => new
{
  Appeal = a,
  Persons = a.AppealPersons
    .Select(ap => ap.Person)
    .Select(p => new { p.Surname, p.Name, p.MiddleName })
    .ToList()
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(a => new
{
  Id = a.Appeal.Id,
  Persons = a.Persons.Select(p => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", p.Surname, p.Name, p.MiddleName).Trim()),
})
.ToList<object>();
```

**This query is very slow. List for ~500 rows generated in 30 seconds.**
Please help to optimize query.

Comment: did you check sql - profiler? does it generates one sql query or do a query for each appeal?

Answer (score 0):

Try with joins such as:

```
from a in context.Appeals
join ap in context.AppealPerson
on a.Id equals ap.AppealId
join p in context.Person
on p.Id equals ap.PersonId
...
```

Comment: Surely joins would be slower?

Comment: And how to concatenate fullnames?

Comment: @James no necessarily, his LINQ query may be generating several SQL queries, that's why I'd proposed giving it a try.

Comment: @PiONeeR I'd still go with calling `.AsEnumerable()` to bring the results and perform that with `string.Format` as you are doing. I was targeting the base SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your relationships, I think you can do this with a `GroupBy` clause. Given the formatting has to happen client-side it would be a bit less cluttered if you either had a function which wrapped up this or, even better, override `ToString` on `Person`

```
public partial class Person
{
    ...
    public string override ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Surname, Name, MiddleName).Trim();
    }
}
...
context.AppealPersons
    .GroupBy(ap => ap.Appeal.Id, ap => ap,
        (key, g) => new { 
            AppealId = key, 
            Appeal = g.FirstOrDefault().Appeal, 
            Persons = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Person).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(p => p.ToString()))
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a question: If appeal haven't any persons is this appear in query result?

Comment: `Persons` should return an empty string in that case, you should still get the `Appeal` info though because you are grouping by `Appeal.Id`, person is really just extra metadata you are appending to the results.

Comment: You should know that if appeal haven't any persons, then there is no any AppealPerson with this Appeal.Id. I want to show appeals with no persons too.

Comment: @PiONeeR if that's the case then you will get no results. We are querying the `AppealPerson` table directly here so it will only give us back records that exist...